# Include audio files in PDF after the end of Flash

Tags: pdf, media9, acrobat, audio

Usually I include audio files via FlashPlayer in PDF documents with the Media9 package:

```
\usepackage{media9}
\addmediapath{./folder}

\includemedia[
transparent,
passcontext,
addresource=audio.mp3,
flashvars={source=audio.mp3},
]{\color{gray}{\tiny\faCircle}}{APlayer.swf}
```

Since Acrobat stopped supporting FlashPlayer. this is no longer possible. However, including audios is still possible:
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html

Can somebody help me on how to go about including the audios? What parts of my code do I need to change?

Comment: Hi, did you succeed with that? I'm also trying to include sound in my tikz figure.

Answer (score 0):

The needed players are included in the package repository at Github:
https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9
I've just tested it myself.  I downloaded Aplayer.swf, put it in the same folder as my latex document, and used similar code to what you have above.  Everything worked!